# Java Files "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

When I try to execute this code throws `"main" java.lang.NullPointerException`. I'm using Netbeans 7.3 and Windows 7.

```
public class Inet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File directorio = new File("C:\\");
        listarDirectorio(directorio);
    }

    public static void listarDirectorio(File directorio) {
        File[] ficheros = directorio.listFiles();

        for (int x = 0; x < ficheros.length; x++) {
            if (ficheros[x].isDirectory()) {
                listarDirectorio(ficheros[x]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ficheros[x].getAbsolutePath() + ficheros[x].getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the debugger to find out what is null.

Comment: ¿Cuál línea lanza la NullPointerException?

Comment: Necesitamos ver toda la excepción.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels im native spanish speaker but instead of `echa` use `lanza` xD

Comment: private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
        getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
}

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer might be, `File#listFiles` can return `null` if the abstract `File` is not a valid path....

This can happen under Windows if you try and follow a `.lnk` or special folder like `My Music`

Try checking for a `null` result before processing the list...

```
File[] ficheros = directorio.listFiles();
if (ficheros != null && ficheros.length > 0) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting **NullPointerException Exception.**

That means some where else in code `null` is return.and you can not proceed with null value.

**In You code.**

```
File[] ficheros = directorio.listFiles();
```

You are getting **null** value here`(If directory is not found or other reason.)`.

So you have to require checking mechanism like

`ficheros != null` **or** `ficheros.length != 0`

```
if (ficheros != null && ficheros.length != 0) {
//your code here
}
```